# Auto-Rig Pro rendered picture has weird shapes

Tags: auto-rig-pro

I rigged my skeleton with Auto-Rig Pro. When I render weird shapes become visible.
Anyone knows how to get rid of these shapes?

[image: Rednered picture has weird shapes]

All the best,

Anže

Comment: Check in the Outliner if there are objects which are hidden for viewport but not for render.